# SQL Common Table Expression (CTE) JOIN's not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

To anyone who can help. I am not an expert at T-SQL so I am coming here for some guidance. I have a Common Table Expression with two columns that have user id’s. I need to get the name from the user table based on those ID’s so I display the name. Using my CTE with INNER JOINS reduce my record count and I do not know why.

**UPDATE** I am sorry I should have been more clear. No error. Unexpected results. Before the joins I was returning 135 records. With the joins I get 6.

Here is the SQL:

```
;WITH CTE
    AS (SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ChangeRequests].[F0] 
                                    ORDER BY [ChangeRequests].[F8] DESC) AS RN
        FROM [S37] AS [ChangeRequests])
SELECT [CTE].[F0] AS [ID]
    ,[CTE].[F8] AS [RevisionNumber]
    ,[CTE].[F18] AS [ChangeNumber]
    ,[CTE].[F19] AS [Synopsis]
    --,[CTE].[F30] AS [Responsibility]
    ,[CTE].[F32] AS [Description]
    ,(CASE [CTE].[F42] WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE dbo.ConvertSTTimestamp([CTE].[F42]) END) AS [EnteredOn]
    ,[CTE].[F51] AS [Usr_Project]
    --,[CTE].[F52] AS [Usr_CoResponsibility]
    ,[CTE].[F59] AS [Usr_ReportedBy]
    ,[CTE].[F61] AS [Usr_StarFlowStatus]
    ,[Users1].[F7] AS [Responsibility]
    ,[Users2].[F7] AS [CoResponsibility]
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN [S3] [Users1] ON [Users1].[F0] = [CTE].[F30]
INNER JOIN [S3] [Users2] ON [Users2].[F0] = [CTE].[F52]
WHERE (RN = 1)
```

How do I do a JOIN based on my 2 user ID columns to get the user name?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "not working"?  An Error, unexpected results?  Please provide an example of what you started with, what you expected, and what you actually got.

Comment: I am sorry I should have been more clear. No error. Unexpected results. Before the joins I was returning 135 records. With the joins I get 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s, and tell us what you get, and if it's any closer to what you want/expect...